# How to record the position of text on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

What I'm trying to do is allow the user to select a piece of text on the page and highlight it, then be able to load this selection and re-highlight it on further visits (with purely client side JavaScript, I intend to package this into a Chrome extension in future).

I am selecting the text with `window.getSelection`, but AFAIK this doesn't give me any kind of index or placement data about the selected text (or element).

The only way I can currently think of is to record the actual text and search for it, but this raises the problem of uniqueness (the same string of text is likely to appear multiple times on a given page). Is there a way of traversing the DOM tree upwards and storing the 'path' to the containing element (and then only having to worry about uniqueness within that one element)? I'd be happy with that if there isn't a better way.

Thanks

Edit: what I am doing right now is something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/e3XX6/

Comment: how are you planning to keep state of what they choose? or is that your question?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using so far to get this string? The code would be useful in your question, a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be even more useful.

Comment: Brad: I am trying to figure out a way of keeping the state (knowing where the text is to re-select on a subsequent pageload)

@DavidThomas Thanks for the suggestion, added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you examined the `selection` object returned by the `getSelection()` method? For example, it has an `anchorNode` property that in turn has a `parentElement` property. That last property will tell you the element that contains the text.

See this version of your fiddle (open your console!): http://jsfiddle.net/e3XX6/1/

Also, since you're going to make this a Chrome Extension, I'd just recommend using HTML5 Web Storage to remember the selection.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a great deal (I wasn't aware of the `parentElement` property)

Comment: For more info on `Selection` objects, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection

Comment: You also might want to look into https://code.google.com/p/rangy/, especially if you need to start working with ranges in different browsers.

Comment: Thanks, but I only require this to work in Chrome (I know I had begun with some cross browser code, but I've changed my mind and plan for this)